# shared counters and java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I was checking an example, and tested it and got different outputs for each run.. here's the code:

```
    public class Th1 implements Runnable{
        private int i=0;
        public void run(){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex){
            }
            while(i<10){
                System.out.println(i);
                i+=1;
            } } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Th1 t = new Th1();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
```

and here's the first run output

```
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    0
```

second run output:

```
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
```

as I know, the explanation of the first output is that every thread has it own cache, the second thread started at last, printed it's i (0), and when it checks memory to edit i by increment, it finds that the real value is 10, so it becomes 11, and exits the loop.
but why the second run has only one zero??

Comment: there are no visibility guarantees on non synchronized code in multi threaded environment

Comment: you mean that System.out.println is executing but there's no visible result?

Comment: But this doesn't need to have to do with visibility guarantees. I could just be that both threads looks at `i`, sees that it's `0`, one thread continues to run the loop and terminates, the other thread prints `0` and terminates. It's not like `while (i < 10) { sysout(i); i += 1; }` is atomic. In the second run, it could very well be that `t1` runs to completion while `t2` is still in the (last millisecond) of the `sleep` call, and as a consequence, `t2` never enters the loop body.

Comment: no, in second run Thread#2 saw that i=10 after sleep and terminated

Comment: @SashaSalauyou but they use same runnable

Comment: @AdamSkywalker oh, yes )) my mistake. My apologies to OP.

Comment: @aioobe I get the same results without sleep line

Comment: @user3379482, that doesn't change anything. `t1` could then fully complete it's execution before `t2` even gets to run, no?

Comment: threads assign it's cache at creation time ( Thread t2 = new Thread(t);) not at start time

Comment: when t2 enters run, it should have i=0 in cache

Comment: In Java, threads doesn't cache any object or variable, they just have a reference to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [@Gunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5259945/gunner) and [@mel3kings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2023728/mel3kings)
Actually threads running parallel to each other and OS may allow one thread more time instead next one.

Scenario 1;

```
   loop     Thread1              Thread2
    t1     sleep                sleep
    t2     started to loop      started the loop
    t4     print 0              print 1
    t5     print 2              print 3
    t6     print 4              print 5
    t7     print 6              print 7
    t8     print 8              print 9
    t9     print 10             exit to loop
```

Scenario 2

```
   loop       Thread1              Thread2
    t1     sleep                sleep
    t2     started to loop      
    t4     print 0              
    t5     print 1              
    t6     print 2              
    t7     print 3              
    t8     print 4              started loop
    t9     ..................................
```

Scenario 3 (Also possible)

```
   loop       Thread1              Thread2
    t1     sleep                sleep
    t2     started to loop      started loop
    t3     print 0              send i to print
    t4     print 1              
    t5     print 2              
    t6     print 3              
    t7     print 4              
    t8     print 5              
    t9     print 6              
    t10     print 7              
    t11     print 8
    t12     print 9
    t13     exit             print 0 (delay of console output may cause that)
```

Also there are other output scenarios.

Anyway to see its details try below code with thread names and see which thread print each output

```
public class Th1 implements Runnable {
    private int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        while (i < 10) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Th1 t = new Th1();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

Output

```
Thread-1: 0
Thread-1: 1
Thread-1: 2
Thread-0: 0  //last zero may comes from here but print order is about console
Thread-1: 3  
Thread-1: 4
Thread-1: 5
Thread-1: 6
Thread-1: 7
Thread-1: 8
Thread-1: 9
```

Comment: thanks but what kind of delay is gonna print another zero?

Comment: @user3379482 These are about threads. With threads you can not guarantee to run a line before another. Flushing to console may cause that. As you see example code output(with name) print queue is different than code(without name), but output is actually same (also sometimes :D )

Answer (score 1):

On the second run, T2 "wakes up too late" and T1 already incremented i to 10, so T2 will not enter the while loop. I think the first run is the weird one to be honest.

Comment: threads assign it's cache at creation time ( Thread t2 = new Thread(t);) not at start time

Comment: What does this have to do with it? The variable is shared by both threads, because they use the same runnable. When T1 writes i, T2 will see the modification (you can't tell when, but it will).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `T1 and T2` runs at the same time, during `t1.start();` and `t2.start()`, at this time `i = 0`, `T1` sleeps and `T2` sleeps, `T1` wakes and proceeds to check if i < 10, prints out 1-9, however `T2` wakes but still not run by the JVM, know that once a thread exits the sleep state does not necessary mean it will immediately run. Once `T2` runs, i is still 0, it checks if it is < 10, which it is so it prints out 0, it then amends the plus 1 however `i` has already changed value, and results in to 11. hence does not print anymore

Second run, T1 finishes before T2 executes and i is already 10. There is no guarantees on when threads actually run.

Comment: thanks but that's the first run explanation.. I'm talking about the second one

Comment: The second run is even easier to explain: `t2` doesn't enter the loop until `t1` has run all 10 iterations. Change your `System.out.println` to print `Thread.currentThread() + " " + i`.